# mongoexport syntax error message

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

I'm working with mongodb 2.4.3 and I cannot get mongoexport to work.  The error message I get with each command is:
`"JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"`

At first I thought the problem was with my query parameters, which were long.  But find() worked fine with the query so I know that the syntax is ok.  I then created a new collection using the query and tried exporting the collection with the following:

`mongoexport --db Oct2012 --collection sept8subset --csv --fields "text","created_at","user.screen_name","user.followers_count" --out sept8.csv`

`mongoexport --db Oct2012 --collection sept8subset --csv --fields text,created_at,user.screen_name,user.followers_count --out sept8.csv`

`mongoexport -d Oct2012 -c sept8subset --csv --fields text,created_at,user.screen_name -o sept8.csv`

`mongoexport --db Oct2012 --collection sept8subset --dbpath ~/db (should need dbpath as mongod instance is running)`

`mongoexport --db OCt2012 -collection sept8subset -o sept8.txt`

`mongoexport --db Oct2012 --collection sept8subset`

In each case, I get `"JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"`.  Where could that SyntaxError be??

The collection I'm trying to copy has 50,339 objects.  In case it is just too big for mongoexport to handle, I took 5 documents out of the collection to make a new collection. I then tried to export them using same command structure as above.  I still get the same error message.

Now I'm wondering if the problem is that mongoexport can't work with data involving dates.  MongoDB documentation states that I may want to write my own export script using a client driver.

Does anyone have an idea of what my problem is here?  Many thanks if you can help out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found out that running mongoexport from the mongo client--as I was doing--is incorrect.  Mongoexport is executed at the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too and I solved it executing the command from the **path/bin** where 'mongoexport' is located.In my case :

```
 my_path: /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.4-x86_64/bin

"mongoexport -d book -c shelf"
```

'mongod' is located one step upper from 'mongoimport' , 'mongoexport', etc...

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Looking at it helped me figure out my mistake.